# Congruence of a power of an integer modulo a relatively prime number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm, integers

I'm a complete noob in number theory, and I came across this (probably very elementary) statement: if for all $m\in \mathbb Z/n$ with $\gcd(m,n)=1$ there is some integer $k$ such that $$m^k\equiv 1\mod n,$$ then $k$ must be even. I ask for some help with the proof: I thought about writing explicitly $$m^{2k'+1}-1=nz, \quad z\in \mathbb Z $$ and tried to get a contradiction but I haven't so far managed.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. $2^3\equiv 1 \pmod 7$ for example

Comment: I probably made a mistake; does it make more sense to ask that $m^k\equiv 1$ should hold for all $m\in \mathbb Z/n$ that are relatively prime to $n$?

Comment: If you need a single $k$ to work for all suitable $m$ then, yes. $k$ must be even... Just consider $m=n-1$.

Comment: Yes  that makes more sense.  See Euler's generalization of Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: Should have said: assuming $n\ge 3$.  For $n=2$, we can take $k=1$.